# How do I access a struct that resides within a struct in blueprints?

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints, struct

I have a struct: "`FOuterStruct`"

This is defined in code such that it contains another struct type:

```
Struct OuterStruct
{
    UPROPERTY(...)
        FInnerStruct memberStruct;
}
```

Now.

When I break an `FOuterStruct` apart within blueprints, I do not get the `FInnerStruct` as a pin on the resultant node.

How am I to edit/access this `FInnerStruct`?

Comment: Is `FInnerStruct` declared as `USTRUCT(BlueprintType)`? What's the `...` contain, does it contain any specifiers that indicate that the member is Blueprint-visible?

Comment: Aha. It may be worth mentioning that it's an `FComponentReference`, which is indeed, not declared as `BlueprintType`.

This is weird, because these values can all be edited as defaults, just not inside the event graph.

I'm going to guess that to change this, I'll have to edit `EngineTypes.h` and start building Unreal Engine from source?

Comment: Hey @Josh if you put that as an answer, I'll accept it, as it solved my issue

Comment: @Protoss seems to have posted an answer covering that information, does that suffice?

Comment: @Josh

This is a weird situation, because his answer is technically correct, however your answer made me realize the unreal limitation that led me to ask this question. I guess people may follow both routes to get to this question...

So with that in mind, you think it's best to accept his answer still, considering the actual title of the question?

Comment: Yep - @Protoss went to the trouble of actually writing up an answer; what I posted was a guess and a request for clarification.

Comment: @Josh gotcha. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this.
Define Struct:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MYRROJ_API FMyStruct
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Test")
        int32 Test;

    FMyStruct()
    {

    }
};
```

Usage:

```
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadOnly)
    FMyStruct Test;
```